# join one table on another using 2 variables from first table and get 2 variables in Select

Tags: sql, join

**UPDATE**
Consider 2 Tables.

> Events Table. eventID int pk status1 int status2 int
>
> Status Table ID int pk statusName varchar

now each events has 2 statuses written in int.
And I want to show event rows on the screen but to get corresponding status name from Status table. Thus I have to join events table 2 times to status table. using status1,status2 ints to ID of status table.

While using entity framework I was writing such code

```
 join ds1 in db.Status on te.aStatus equals ds1.ID
 join ds2 in db.Status on te.bStatus equals ds2.ID
select new {
 Status1 = ds1.statusName,
 Status2 = ds2.statusName,
}
```

But now for some reasons I don't want to use Entity Framework , instead of that I want to write this directly in SQL
I can join 2 dbs easely
by

```
    SELECT db.Status.statusName FROM db.Main INNER JOIN
 Status ON dbo.Main.aStatus = dbo.Status.ID"
```

and this will work. but how can I make second join ?

After SELECT I take this DataTable Object and get rows in loop. And in that loop I create from that rows List.
And there I must get 2 statuses

```
        foreach (DataRow item in dtbProduct.Rows)
            {
                StatusList.Add(new JStatus()
                {
Status1= item["statusName"]  ???
Status2=item["statusName"]  ???
```

How can I get here 2 variables for each status ?

Comment: SELECT columns FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON condition(s) JOIN t3 ON condition(s) ... WHERE ...

Comment: how can I write those columns after select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does you find something below

```
 SELECT ds1.statusName,ds2.statusName FROM 
 db.Main d
 join db.Status ds1   on d.aStatus = ds1.ID
 join db.Status ds2   on d.bStatus = ds2.ID
```

Comment: but that's only one variable d.statusName . And I want to get 2

Comment: @David which two variables

Comment: @David better you need to share expected output from the query

Comment: If I try ds1.statusName I get 'Column 'ds1.statusName' does not belong to table .'

Answer (score 0):

```
  $first_status = select status.statusName , events.* from status
    join events on events.status1 = status.id


    $second_status = select status.statusName, events.* from status
    join events on events.status2 = status.id

    foreach($first_status as $key =>status1){

     foreach($second_status as $k=>status2){
      if($first_status[$key]['id']== $second_status[k]['id']){
          $first_status[$key]['second_status']= $status2[$k][statusName]; 
      }
     }
    }
```

Sorry it may help you a little. I just tried to do it with multiple data variables.

Comment: I want to get 2 variables not one db.Status.statusName

Comment: which two variable exactly.. you question only wants answers like this.. please be specific

Comment: can I get the output of the rows?

Comment: Please read the updated question. I've described what I have and what I am trying to do

Comment: updated my answer. I dont think it wont help you much. But something like this can be used as a workaround. $first_status contains both the status names.